# SENDKEYがうまく機能しない

Tags: powershell

よろしくお願いします。

やりたいこと
あるURLをリクエストするとファイルが自動的にダウンロードされます。
この処理を自動化してWindowsのタスクスケジューラーに登録したいと考えています。

下記のシェルを記述してPOWERSHELL ISEでは問題なく動いたのですが、バッチファイルから
呼び出すと以下の部分でエラーが出ます。同様にPOWERSHELLのコマンドプロンプトから実行しても同じエラーが出ます。3日ほど悩んだのですが理由が分からずお分かりになるかとのコメントを頂けると助かります。

やっていることはIEのダウンロードダイヤログボックスで保存ボタンをSendKeyで処理しようとしています。

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%({S})")
```

#### スクリプト

```
$url = "https://hoge.com/?un=userID&pass=password?file=00O7F00000AnYio?export=1"
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

# IE起動
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application

# 可視化
$ie.Visible = $true

# URLオープン(キャッシュ無効)
$ie.Navigate($url,4)

While($ie.Busy)
{ Start-Sleep -s 1 }                                      

Start-Sleep 2 

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%({S})")

Start-Sleep 2 

$ie.Quit()
```

#### 実行例

```
C:\TEST>powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File c:\TEST\sample.ps1
型 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys] が見つかりません。
発生場所 C:\TEST\sample.ps1:21 文字:1
+ [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%({S})")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys
   :TypeName) []、RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

C:\TEST>pause
続行するには何かキーを押してください . . .
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　このサイトではそれぞれの投稿を Markdown として扱っているため、Markdown の文法で特別な意味を持つ記号である角カッコ等がスクリプト中に含まれており、上手く表示できなかったようです。コードブロックとして装飾するように編集してみましたので、何か意図にそぐわぬ所がございましたら追記編集して頂ければと思います。質問文下の「編集」から自由に編集ができます。また、ソースコード部分をマウスカーソルで範囲選択し、エディタ上部の `{}` を押すと自動的にコードブロックとして装飾できますので、次回からお試しください :)

Answer (score 1):

以下を追加したらどうでしょうか。

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

参考: [PowerShellでSendKeysを使ったWindowsの自動化をしてみた](https://qiita.com/nimzo6689/items/488467dbe0c4e5645745#powershell%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85)